# Sorting an array in javascript for a tic tac toe game

Tags: javascript, jquery

I posted earlier about sorting objects in javascript. I've got a big no no about not being able to sort objects.

The path I was told was to transform an object into an array.

**I have declared the totalScore as a new Array and I apply the descending function to it.** - this does not work. Any ideas why?

Here is the code (I am developing a tic tac toe game):

```
var data = {
        "arr0" : ["1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
        "arr1" : ["1","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1"],
        "arr2" : ["0","0","0","1","1","1","0","0","0"],
        "arr3" : ["0","0","0","0","0","0","1","1","1"],
        "arr4" : ["0","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","0"],
        "arr5" : ["1","0","0","1","0","0","1","0","0"],
        "arr6" : ["0","1","0","0","1","0","0","1","0"],
        "arr7" : ["0","0","1","0","0","1","0","0","1"]
    };

function win(){
        var pocket,
            totalScore = new Array,
            score,
            maxM,
            i;

        jQuery.each(data, function(d_key, d_val){
            score = 0;
            i = 0;
            jQuery.each(d_val, function(key, val){
                pocket = jQuery(document).find('[data-kcpos="'+key+'"]');
                if(val == 1 && jQuery(pocket).hasClass("blank")){
                    score += 1;
                } else if(val == 1 && jQuery(pocket).text() == "x"){
                    score += 0;
                } else if(val == 1 && jQuery(pocket).text() == "0"){
                    score += 2;
                }
                if(val == 1) i++;
                if(i == 3) return false;
            });
            totalScore[d_key] = score;
        });


        function descending( a, b ) {
                return b - a;
            }
        totalScore.sort( descending );


    }
```

Comment: A little bit off topic but, don't you mean connect four instead of tic tac toe?

Comment: 6 x's in a row will win - noughts and crosses - some refer to it as tic tac toe - this will be an algo used by the ai to pick a good move

Answer (score -1):

EDIT (Wrong answer to question)

Try :

```
totalScore.sort();
totalScore.reverse();
```

Comment: Brackets are not necessary in this context

Comment: Still does not work, but wow, solly me - ty for poiting out the brackets

Comment: Try declaring in as an object totalScore = {},

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake.

Comment: totalScore.sort();
totalScore.reverse();

Comment: Any other ideas on how I can sort the totalScore array - the move with the biggest score is the best move for the CPU to make.

Answer (score -1):

You are still using an object and not an array. Remeber, in JavaScript everything is an object. So if you define an array:

```
var arr = [];
```

and then add an item to it:

```
arr["arr0"] = 1;
```

your array will have the length 0, but you the object that your array is, will have a new property called `arr0`. That of course means that you're still not able to sort the "array".

A possible fix would be to populate your array with objects, containing the original key, and the value. So instead of `totalScore[d_key] = score;` you can write:

```
totalScore.push({key: d_key, value: score});
```

And now you can write an appropriate sorting function:

```
function descending(a, b) {
    return b.value - a.value;
}
```

Comment: That worked, ty:) But now, how do I use the data, do I need to loop the data and loop through each object?

Comment: I believe I need to use totalScore[0] to get the object with the highest value and then loop it

Comment: @user2065483 what "data" do you mean? I think I can't follow.

Comment: jQuery.each(totalScore[0], function(key, val){
   console.log(key);
   console.log(val);
   
  });

Comment: I am thinking of something like that to manipulate the entry from the totalScore with the highest value

Comment: @user2065483 I updated my answer to address another issue. But to your question about iterating. I'm still not sure if I understand what you're trying to do. But there is no need to iterate over `totalScore[0]`. It's just an object with two properties and you can access them via `totalScore[0].key` and `totalScore[0].value`.

Comment: @Paul sorry, you're right. Looks like I shot too fast. I tested it yesterday in the evening and observed a strange behaviour which made me conclude that it must be asynchronous. Today in the morning, it all works fine. Removed this part of the answer.

Comment: Not a problem.  I found that curious and had to look it up to be certain.